# CSS :Hover Selecting Too Many

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

All, I've searched around and I have a feeling it's something simple. When hovering over any of my navigation items it displays all levels of my navigation bar. I have tried a couple of different ways to select but here is my CSS code.

```css
    div#topnav {
      margin: -1px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 21px;
      background-color: #666;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    div#topnav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0px;
      background: #666;
      text-align: left;
      width: auto;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    div#topnav li {
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 3px 8px 2px 8px;
      float: right;
      border-left: 1px solid silver;
    }
    div#topnav li:hover {
      background-color: #0038A8;
    }
    div#topnav li li.submenu:hover {
      background-color: #0038A8;
    }
    div#topnav li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: auto;
      color: white;
    }
    div#topnav li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    div#topnav>ul a {
      width: auto;
    }
    ul.level2 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 175px;
      display: none;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
    }
    div#topnav ul ul li {
      float: left;
      width: 158px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    }
    div#topnav ul.level2 {
      top: 19px;
      left: -1px;
      margin-top: 2px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    div#topnav ul.level3 {
      top: -1px;
      left: 174px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    ul.level1:hover > li ul.level2 {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="topnav" class="menu">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="level1">
    <li>Help
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>Email us</li>
        <li>Call Us</li>
        <li>Online Support</li>
        <li>Forums</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Shopping
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>Shoes</li>
        <li>Shirts</li>
        <li>Pants</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have also put the CSS as a direct descendant but still had the same problem (Below is what I used).

```
ul.level1:hover > li ul.level2
```

Comment: Try something like: `ul.level1 li:hover > ul.level2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7w68q1f4/

```
ul.level1 li:hover > ul.level2 {
display:block;}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Although, if you don't mind. Why did it work? Was it looking at each li and finding a ul.level2 child?